# Sliding Menu in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a file separator styled menu in react. I'm not very familiar with css, so i need a starting point. I have found many such menu components but all of them are full page.

I dont understand how to create the shape of the component, if it were a simple rectangle it would be possible, but the shape is the rectangle plus the button, i dont know how to manage that.

It will look something like this :

[image: Filter Menu is hidden until clicked on]

Alter clicking on "Filter Menu", it will slide into view:

[image: Filter Menu slides into view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually a CSS/HTML only question.
However, to develop from scratch:

- Draw a two column table and have the button in the second field

Or

- Use Div containers and style them accordingly

Side Note:
Usually you'd use something like bootstrap or even ant.design.
There you have ready to use [table components](https://ant.design/components/table/) with possibility to filter (at least with ant.design) and for the filter seection popup you could use stuff like the modal component.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```css
.menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
}
.menu-body {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.activate-button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu-body">
      
    </div>
    <div class="activate-button">
      
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```